# MongoDB map reduce producing different result to db.collection.find()

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a map reduce like this:

map:

```
function() {
        emit(this.username, {sent:this.sent, received:this.received});
}
```

reduce:

```
function(key, values) {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    var result = {sent: 0, received: 0, entries:0};

    values.forEach(function (value) {
        result.sent += value.sent;
        result.received += value.received;
        result.entries += 1;
    });

    return result;
}
```

I've been monitoring the amount of entries processed in the result map, as you can see. I've found I get much lower numbers of accessed records than I should.

For my particular data set, the output is like so:

[{u'_id': u'1743', u'value': {u'received': 1406545.0, u'sent': 26251138.0, u'entries': 316.0}}]

As I'm running the map reduce with a query option, specifying a username and a date range.

If I perform the same query using db.collection.find() as follows, the count is different:

```
> db.entire_database.find({username: '1743', time : { $lte: ISODate('2011-08-12 12:40:00'), $gte: ISODate('2011-08-12 08:40:00') }}).count()                        
1915
```

The full map reduce query is this:

```
db.entire_database.mapReduce(m, r, {out: 'myoutput', query: { username: '1743', time : { $lte: ISODate('2011-08-12 12:40:00'), $gte: ISODate('2011-08-12 08:40:00') } }  })
```

So basically, I'm unsure why the count is so radically different? Why is the find() giving me 1915, but the map reduce is 316?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `map` function needs to emit an object with the same form as the `reduce` function (ie. it should have an `entries` field set to 1). You can read more about this [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce).

Basically, the values that are passed to the `reduce` function are not necessarily the raw outputs emitted from `map`. Rather than being called once, the `reduce` function is called many times on 'groups' of values produced by `map`, the *results* of which are then combined again by being passed into a further call of the `reduce` function. This is what makes MapReduce horizontally scalable, because any group of emitted values can be farmed out to any server in any order before being combined later.

So I would restructure your functions slightly like this:

map:

```
function() {
    emit(this.username, {sent:this.sent, received:this.received, entries : 1});
}
```

reduce:

```
function(key, values) {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    var result = {sent: 0, received: 0, entries:0};

    values.forEach(function (value) {
        result.sent += value.sent;
        result.received += value.received;
        result.entries += value.entries;
    });

    return result;
}
```